# c# Selenium get a element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="pill-wrap double">
<a ng-click="modalCancel()" class="button pill">No</a>
<a ng-click="modalSuccess()" class="button pill">Yes</a>
</div>
```

I want to get the button with class button pill and where the innertext is 'No' and click it

Comment: Great! What is your question? Where is your code, problem description?

Comment: I just don't know how to do it @Andersson

Comment: @refactorcoding, the idea is that you go and read a tutorial, then if you can't make it work, come here and show us what you've tried. No pain, no gain.

Comment: You could just use `driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("No")).Click();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the button with innertext as **No** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='pill-wrap double']//a[@class='button pill' and @ng-click='modalCancel()']")).Click();
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work https://secure.runescape.com/m=world11/html5/comapp/login

Comment: I have to tell you it pops it up in another window

Comment: Worked with ChromeDriver, didn't work with PhantomJSDriver